# Button click is not working in usercontrol Umbraco

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms, umbraco

I started to build a website using Umbraco and I noticed that button click events (and probably other events) are not working.

I created simplest usercontrol with one button, added it to a page, When I debug it the Page_Load is called (breakpoint being hit), but not button click.

The code is very standard, but here it is:

.aspx file

```
<%@ Control Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="TestControl.ascx.cs" Inherits="usercontrols_TestControl" %>

<asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="Button" onclick="Button1_Click" />
<asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text="Label"></asp:Label>
```

and code behind:

```
protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) {
    Label1.Text = "Button clicked!";
}
```

Where can be the problem?

Comment: Is the designer file not being created? That's what hooks up the control with the code.

Comment: @MichaelTodd no, it's not the only usercontrol where events don't work, there are others as well, anyway I updated it as above, but still no luck.

Comment: Did you set the [`AutoEventWireUp="true"` in your @Control directive](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d19c0t4b.aspx) to true?

Comment: @dludlow designer files are created fine.

Comment: @UweKeim it's true by default, I didn't shange it.

Comment: Maybe it is turned off in the web.config file?

Comment: I don't even have `AutoEventWireup` in my web.config

Comment: How do you add it to your masterpage? as a macro through code, as a macro in an editor or as a regular user control?

Comment: @Burjua: Is it placed in a template with master template?. Is there any styles are added for this. If yes, then can you please check this by adding to a plane template, ie without any html...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make sure you are wrapping your body with `<form runat="server">...</form>` tags, the user control/macro should be inside the `form` tags. Also ensure that you are adding the user control correctly. To help you out with this, here are a few resources:

1. [A demo by Niels Hartvig](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=F9NV9a9pQ6Q). (Niels is using a current Umbraco version.)
2. [Tim Geyssens' screencast](http://www.nibble.be/?p=12). (Tim is using an older version of Umbraco in the screencast (not 4.7.*), but there isn't much difference.)
3. [Step-by-step instructions](http://skiltzonnet.blogspot.com/2008/01/creating-you-first-umbraco-user-control.html) by Skiltz.

Comment: Thanks for answer, I also asked this question on Umbraco forum and we advanced a little bit more there. It's here: http://our.umbraco.org/forum/core/general/32862-Button-click-is-not-working-in-usercontrol-Umbraco I do have `<form runat="server">...</form>` tag but it actualy depends on where I place this tag. Do you mind to have a look at that conversation?

Comment: Ok, we figured out where the problem is. It indeed had to do with `<form runat="server">...</form>` tags and their placement. See Umbraco forum thread here http://our.umbraco.org/forum/core/general/32862-Button-click-is-not-working-in-usercontrol-Umbraco I will mark this answer as solution anyway as it is partly correct.